# C++ - Singleton Pattern, a few questions about private member functions

Tags: c++, constructor, singleton, overloading, destructor

I'm confused about the singleton pattern. To my understanding,

- It is a class that allows only one object to be created from it.
- To do this, the constructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator overloading function are made private to prevent any other objects from being created.
- The one and only instance is made public in the class and is static. Its default value is NULL.
- A function, usually called getInstance() or something similar, is used to allocate memory for the static object if it hasn't been done already

So my question is what do the constructors and copy constructor and &operator=() functions look like? Also will the destructor be public or private?

```
class Database {
 private:
  Database() {
   //???
  }
  Database(const Database &db) {
   //???
  }
  Database &operator=(const Database &db) {
   //???
  }
  //~Database() {...}
 public:
  static Database database = NULL;
  Database &getDB() {
   if (database == NULL) {
    database = new Database();
    return database;
   } 
   return database;
  }
  ~Database() {...}
}
```

Comment: The constructor is just like any normal constructor, it does any needed initialisation / resource gathering. Copy constructor and assignment are empty, a singleton should/can not be copied anyway. By making them private or deleting them you make sure no-one can use them.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What about the destructor?

Comment: @thisisalongdisplayname Destructor calls for singletons are implementation defined. If you have one for your example using `new`, you'll need to provide another static function `destruct()` and call it whenever your program ends.

Comment: Oh. And should it be public or private? Thanks again